# In SAS, how do you obtain the folder in which the file is located?

Tags: sas

In SAS, how do you obtain the folder in which the file is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my solution but I thought I would share it here. The original can be found at http://www.stats.uwa.edu.au/Internal/sas_tips#currentFolder